# Write typedef function

Tags: c

In the header file I have the following line:

```
typedef int comparator(int* left, int* right);
```

But when I tried to write a function definition for it like so:

```
int comparator (int* left, int* right){
    if(left<right) {
        return 1;
    } else if(right>left) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }   
}
```

The error I get is:

> file.c:10: error: ‘comparator’ redeclared as different kind of symbol

The function must be typedef'ed because later on in the header file it is used in a method prototype like so:

```
struct bst_node** search(struct bst_node** root, comparator compare, void* data);
```

So how is this method constructed?

Comment: Call them functions instead of methods. Methods means member functions of a class.

Comment: Also, minor stylistic remark: `int *left;` is preferred over `int* left;`.

Comment: @Pubby I realised that when I click answer.

Comment: @H2CO3 that's actually no more than a personal preference... but I don't want to start another war about that. :)

Comment: @effeffe there's a serious reasoning behind it, trust me.

Comment: there's arguments both ways,  when you think of pointer as type, it feels best on the left,  however technically it's not the type, and associated with the variable....  eg   int* a,b   won't do what you expect if you are thinking about it as a type

Comment: @KeithNicholas I don't understand... _"technically"_ the pointer is part of the type.

Comment: @effeffe syntax wise,  you end up with a int pointer, but the pointer part is associated with the variable.   ie,  int* a,b;   makes 'a' a pointer and b a int.... the * part is a modifier to the variable to make it a pointer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your header file you should just have

```
 int comparator(int* left, int* right);
```

your aren't declaring a type, but just declaring a function.

you could declare a function pointer type called comparator...

```
typedef int (*comparator)(int* left, int* right);
```

but you wouldn't then make a function called comparator.   you just need to make a function with the same signature

```
int ascending_comparator(int* left, int* right)
{
    // comparison
}
```

then call

```
search(root, ascending_comparator, data);
```

Also, I got a feeling you don't want to be passing int*  but actual int,  or in your function you don't want to be comparing the pointers, but comparing the values of what each int is pointing to,  like

```
int comparator (int* left, int* right){
    if(*left < *right) {
        return 1;
    } else if(*right > *left) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }   
}
```

but possibly you are wanting to compare the memory locations where the ints are stored.

also your comparisons are the same

```
if(left < right)
```

is the same as

```
if( right > left)
```

so maybe you want

```
 int comparator (int* left, int* right){
        if(*left < *right) {
            return 1;
        } else if(*left > *right) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: @KeithNicholas See my comment on H2CO3's answer.

Comment: @Dean  now you reworded your question thats the second bit.  I'll add a function pointer example

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you don't actually want to create a typedef, rather you want to declare the function using a prototype. It's sufficient to write

```
int comparator(int *left, int *right);
```

Comment: Reason for the downvote of this question and Keith Nicolas' one?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, the question is if a function is typedef'd then how is it defined. As with Keith Nicolas' one.

Comment: @Dean Well, the question you asked was not clear, so you can't blame on us the misunderstanding.

Comment: Ahh ok i'll reedit my question to make it a little more clear.

Comment: @KeithNicholas well, actually, it's possible: `typedef retval (funcname)();` <- this defines a function type, which is not the same as a function pointer.

Comment: @H2CO3 I think he was talking about functions, not function (pointer) types.

Comment: sure, you can makea type, I mean thats not the same as creating an actual function

Answer (score 2):

If the `typedef` is not a mistake, you now have a type called `comparator` and you cannot use this identifier for a function, no matter if the existing type is a function pointer, it would be the same as writing this:

```
typedef int myType;

int myType(int, int);
```

You can use that `typedef` in something like this:

```
typedef int (* comparator)(int, int);

int comparison(int, int);
void sort(int [], comparator);

int main(void)
{
  int array[10];
  sort(array, comparison);
}
```

If you're looking for a function declaration and that `typedef` was a mistake, then other answers already provide you the solution.

**EDIT**: Maybe I'm wrong, but reading comments, it seems like you're expecting too much from `typedef`. Functions have their types (`main` could have type `int ()(void)` or `int ()(int, char **)`), and you're just saying that `comparator` can be used as a type and it means `int ()(int *, int *)`.

If you write:

```
typedef double real;
```

You're not creating (technically, *defining*) any `double` object, you're just saying "from now on, `real` means `double`".

Comment: No typedef isn't a mistake, although I still don't understand how the function is defined.

Comment: Which function? `typedef` declares a new function type, but it doesn't declare any function. That's there just because `comparator` is clearer than `int (*)(int, int)`.

Comment: Maybe, but its when I call the function to search and it has a parameter of compare, how would I do that? I thought I needed to have defined a function.

Comment: @Dean not _"maybe"_, it's sure. Anyway, I put an example in my answer. You need to declare a function with a name different from comparator, taking two pointers to `int` and returning an `int`, and then pass the function to the search function, just like a variable. (sorry, forgot to notify you in my previous comment)